# What does <<< operator in php exactly do?

Tags: php

I have seen the <<< operator many times , but I can't find any mention of this operator in PHP documentation. Can anyone please tell what this operator exactly does?

Comment: HEREDOC, show an example of where uu saw it

Comment: @Ibu: what an example would change ))) It always behaves in the same way, like it is explained in documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @zerkms Just want to provide a specific explanation.

Comment: @Ibu: heredoc is as simple as `+`, so for every developer manual should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full explanation here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

[With a bit easier explanation here.](http://www.poundbangwhack.com/2010/07/02/what-is-heredoc/)

> Heredoc syntax is a way to delimit
>   strings in PHP (and other languages)
>   with 3 “less than” symbols: <<<.

The good part about it:

> Heredoc text behaves just like a
>   double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes
>   in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped. Variables are expanded, but
>   the same care must be taken when
>   expressing complex variables inside a
>   heredoc as with strings.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I wanted !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one place where it is used

```
$longString = <<<STR

This is a String and this method of creating it is called HEREDOC

STR;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<<<` is the opener for the HEREDOC syntax. You follow it by an arbitrary string which is used as terminator. It's alternative syntax to quotes. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc